# Can someone give examples for addDataQueueListener() in as400 dataqueue class

Tags: java, db2, ibm-midrange

I want to listen to an AS400 DataQueue using java. I don't want to use dataqueue.read(-1) since it is getting stopped when an interrupt occurs. So I came across addDataQueueListener() in as400 dataqueue class, But couldn't find any examples in internet for this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a listener, you can wrap your dataqueue.read() in a loop and a try/catch. If you get an InterruptedException, loop around.

I'm assuming that these interrupts seldom occur and that your code is not generating them for some purpose. "Spurious" interrupts can happen in Java and may be ignored.

Comment: I tried using it. But after a couple of days (or sometimes on the same day) the loop execution is stopped and the message is still the queue.  could not find any error message of being this loop stopped or anything like that.

Comment: I suggest catching Exception instead and logging the error. I suspect something other than an interrupt is breaking your read. *Depending on the problem*, you could just ignore the error and loop.

Comment: Do you have any examples of the the addDataQueueListener method?